# Error in do.call(rbind, x) with qtm() and openstreetmaps

Tags: r, openstreetmap, tmap

I am trying to build a map of a federate state in germany with special borders (voting districts):

```
install.packages("OpenStreetMap")
install.packages("sf")
install.packages("osmdata")
install.packages("tmap")

library(OpenStreetMap)
library(sf)
library(osmdata)
library(tmap)


## I use this because the other overpass server didnt work that well    
set_overpass_url("https://overpass-api.de/api/interpreter")

##open the map of "baden-württemberg" and get the right boundaries, timeout is increased because the map is big and it sometimes timed out

boundaries <- opq(bbox = getbb("baden-württemberg"), timeout = 900) %>%
      add_osm_feature(key = 'admin_level', value = '6') %>%
      add_osm_feature(key = "boundary", value = "administrative") %>%
      osmdata_sf() %>% unique_osmdata()
    
    qtm(boundaries$osm_multipolygons)
```

I get

```
Error in do.call(rbind, x) : variable names are limited to 10000 bytes
```

It should approxamitly look something like this:

```
boundaries <- opq(bbox = 'Brussels, Belgium') %>%
  add_osm_feature(key = 'admin_level', value = '8') %>% 
  osmdata_sf %>% unique_osmdata

municipalities <- boundaries$osm_multipolygons

qtm(municipalities)
```

with the resulting plot:
[[image: Belgium Plot1]

Comment: Always include at least `library` call for non-core packages. Better yet would be to include a conditional that would install package(s) when it(they) are rather thinly used and then load the package.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I added the install.packages() and library() calls!

Answer (score 1):

It appears to be related to the geometry of some features.

This works:

```
qtm(boundaries$osm_multipolygons$geometry[c(1,3,5,6,7,8,9)])
```

[image]

but including features 2 or 4 causes the failure. Note by plotting the geometry I've excluded the possibility of it being a problem with the attributes. They are out of the picture.

I can't immediately see anything wrong with feature 2 and 4's geometries. They both pass the `st_is_valid` test, unlike feature 3 which fails (but will `qtm` okay):

```
> st_is_valid(boundaries$osm_multipolygons$geometry[1:4])
[1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
```

so that's weird.

The trick of fixing bad geometries by zero-buffering gets us past the error to a full plot:

```
> qtm(st_buffer(boundaries$osm_multipolygons,0))
dist is assumed to be in decimal degrees (arc_degrees).
Warning message:
In st_buffer.sfc(st_geometry(x), dist, nQuadSegs, endCapStyle = endCapStyle,  :
  st_buffer does not correctly buffer longitude/latitude data
```

[image]

(but I'm not sure if the holes seen here are errors).

Boiling this down further thanks to the error  `traceback()` it occurs in `st_as_grob` which evokes this method:

```
> g = sf:::st_as_grob.sfc_MULTIPOLYGON(boundaries$osm_multipolygons$geometry[1])
> g = sf:::st_as_grob.sfc_MULTIPOLYGON(boundaries$osm_multipolygons$geometry[2])
Error in do.call(rbind, x) : variable names are limited to 10000 bytes
```

Debugging that method, the code does a recursive `unlist` which results in an object with a very long name for any feature. Features 2 and 4 (and others) take it over the 10000 char limit, it seems. When it tries to `rbind` everything, the names are too long.

The buffer trick works because it returns an object with *no* rownames on the geometry, so the constructed name before the `rbind` is NULL. Which is fine, these names serve no real purpose here.

The name looks like its the OSM ID of each vertex. The fix would be either for the `opq` maintainers to not attach the OSM ID to each vertex (which is bloating the size of the resulting R objects as well) or for the `sf` authors to strip dimnames of underlying geometry objects to stop this happening. But I'm not sure if that will break existing code.

Possibly worth an issue report to `osmdata` and `sf` - its not a `tmap` bug. For a temporary fix, the `st_buffer` trick seems to work, or recursively set all rownames on the relevant bits of the object to NULL, or maybe something else...

Comment: Filed as an issue here https://github.com/r-spatial/sf/issues/1678

Comment: Thank you so much for your lengthy answer. I only understand 10% of what you wrote, but after your post (and some further research) I could identify that the problem was not on my side. It is a problem with osmdata that is fixed (with the current developement version). with the call unname_osmdata_sf() the problem is solved and qtm() is working (I will add that as an answer to my own question, if nodody posts another solution). The current cran vignette is fairly new 2021-03-22 but I dont think unname_osmdata_sf() is in that version.

Comment: Ultimate cause is R itself, but with very clear error message here - if rownames were allowed to be > 10,000 bytes, there'd be no problem, but they aren't. In the meantime, the "official" solution is as @BanffBoss122 says, just to pipe final result through `unname_osmdata_sf()`.